# "to or while " for preposition

Tags: prepositions

"The daybed  always seemed to help her fall asleep to sort through whatever mystery was on her mind."

Can you please make me understand the use of" to"  between fall asleep and sort through?  To me it should have been "while", and how does it change the sense?

Comment: The implication is that sleep is necessary for sorting. The daybed alone is not enough.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence, Mshamim? 'Help someone to fall asleep to get some rest' say sounds at best clumsy to me; I'd want 'Help someone to fall asleep so that they can get some rest'.

Answer (score 1):

The use of **to** in the sentence means that it's sleep that allows her to sort through her mysteries.

It might make more sense if you consider a version with some elided words re-added:

> The daybed always seemed to help her fall asleep ***in order*** **to** sort through whatever mystery was on her mind.

The daybed helps her to fall asleep—and its sleep she needs before she can sort through her mysteries. (They will no doubt be solved by her unconscious.)

As for **while**, you can't just substitute it without making another change to the sentence:

> The daybed always seemed to help her fall asleep **while** ***sorting*** through whatever mystery was on her mind.

With this change, the daybed helps her fall asleep whenever she is already in the process of sorting through mysteries. Perhaps sorting through mysteries keeps her awake when all she wants is to stop thinking about them—so she resorts to her daybed.

(In another interpretation of this sentence—but not one that anybody would normally make—it's the daybed itself that is sorting through the mysteries on her mind, and the daybed helps her fall asleep while *it* continues the process of its sorting. But that could only make sense if, for instance, it was a magic daybed in a fantasy story.)